# sudoers: allow users to remove from their home directory

Tags: sudo, sudoers

I'd like to add a sudoers rule that says users are allowed to remove files from their home directory , but I don't see any way to limit arguments to be a subdirectory of the users' home.

Is there any way to do this?

```
users localhost=/bin/rm -rf $HOME/*
```

Comment: Why would a user need to use sudo to remove a file from their own home directory?  Don't they already own everything under that folder?  If you have some software writing to that folder with the wrong permissions, then you should probably be looking at solving this with ACLs so the user actually has rights to their own files.

Comment: It's quite easy to create files that you don't have permissions to remove with docker. This is a usability bug that is being worked on, but it's not fixed now. In any case, it has little bearing on the question at hand.

Comment: And you are sure acls wouldn't solve this?

Comment: ACLs certainly won't help me configure sudo the way I've asked. It also won't help with docker because the permissions are entirely clobbered.